# Как заменить пиксели в картинке через python?

Tags: python, numpy, pillow

Как заменить каждый 2-й пиксель в картинке на прозрачный? Смог разбить картинку через numpy но как заменить каждое второе значение не разобрался

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Меняйте альфа-канал, т.е. четвёртую компоненту цветовых свойств пикселя `RGBA` - вот это вот `A`. Только я не помню когда прозрачность - когда там `0` или когда `255`. Всё сразу удобно менять через срезы.

Comment: вопрос как раз в этом, как это изменить

Comment: ну вам же подсказали - через срезы. с шагом. ищите numpy slices with step

Comment: А вообще тут нужно уточнить - картинка у вас уже ф формате `RGBA` с альфа-каналом или у вас `RGB` и альфа-канал нужно ещё добавить к картинке?

Comment: [кучно пошли](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1489759/178576)

Comment: @aleksandrbarakin Ну там вроде немного про другое. Или вы думаете они на самом деле решают одну и ту же задачу? )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для прозрачности нужно RGBA, чтобы записать альфа-канал и сохранять лучше в формате, что поддерживает прозрачность (jpg не подойдет)

ℹ️ В коде `0, 0, 0, 0` это и есть `R`, `G`, `B`, `A`. Значение A = 255 - пиксель непрозрачен, а 0 - прозрачный

[Пример:](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/blob/69d8fe812f6bc4f3ff845debc87cbdca0741039d/pil_pillow__examples/set_transparent_pixels/main.py)

```
from PIL import Image


file_name = "путь до картинки"

img = Image.open(file_name).convert('RGBA')
pixels = img.load()
width, height = img.size

for i in range(width):
    for j in range(height):
        if (j + i) % 2 == 0:
            pixels[i, j] = 0, 0, 0, 0

img.save("output.png")
```

Загружал `input.jpg`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1):

Данную задачу можно решить с помощью библиотеки PIL. Код максимально тривиальный. Открываем нашу картинку, получаем список со всеми пикселями, пробегаемся по каждому второму пикселю и меняем его значение на (255, 255, 255), то есть на белый цвет.

```
from PIL import Image

im = Image.open("name.jpg")
pixels = im.load()  # список с пикселями
x, y = im.size  # ширина (x) и высота (y) изображения

for i in range(x):
    for j in range(y):
        if (j + i) % 2 == 0:
            pixels[i, j] = 255, 255, 255
im.save("new.jpg")
```

Правда не совсем понятно что имеете ввиду под "каждый 2-й пиксель", но это вы уже сами можете изменить условие в if.

Comment: Так то решение рабочее. Но попиксельно скорее всего долго менять. Хотя смотря разовая это задача или промышленная и какого размера картинки. И да, вы же не компоненту `A` меняете, т.е. не прозрачность, как требовалось в вопросе. Хотя я с этой прозрачностью и сам не уверен.

Comment: Да, под прозрачностью я подумал просто белый цвет. Тогда возможно не совсем верно ответил

Comment: С альфой должно быть что-то типа `pixels[i, j, 3] = 0`, но нужно проверять, я не уверен.

Comment: ответ помог, сделал просто вот так pixels[i, j] = 0, 0, 0, 0

Comment: А разве в таком случае не будет каждый второй пиксель черным?

Comment: Как я понял, чтобы изменять прозрачность, нужно изначально конвертировать все пиксели в формат RGBA, и уже затем для каждого указать прозрачность. Вот тут оказывается уже поднимали схожий вопрос https://stackoverflow.com/questions/765736/how-to-use-pil-to-make-all-white-pixels-transparent

Comment: @Leukemia А не важно какого цвета будет пиксел, если он будет полностью прозрачным ))  Так что `0, 0, 0, 0` сработает, просто это не очень красиво. )